# Error Error in storage.mode(x) <- "double" : 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Tags: r, syntax-error

I am trying to run a correlation matrix. My variables are numeric. I am unsure why I keep getting this message?

```
nmdata_y1 <- read.csv(X, header = TRUE)
View(nmdata_y1)
sapply(nmdata_y1, class)
nmdata_y1 <- lapply(nmdata_y1, as.numeric)
table(nmdata_y1$GRADEY1)
library("Hmisc")
nm_corr_y1 <- rcorr(as.matrix(nmdata_y1))
```

which gives the error

> Error in storage.mode(x) <- "double" :
>     'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: Try `nmdata_y1[] <- lapply(nmdata_y1, as.numeric)` as otherwise it is converted to a list (ps; its always worth looking back at your data too see if it looks as you expect. I find the function `str` useflu)

Comment: run the code line by line. After which line does the error appear?

Comment: I think that error suggests you have an embedded `list` within your `nmdata_y1` (which is really just a `list` in itself). Please include the output from `str(nmdata_y1)` or `dput(head(nmdata_y1))` (or both), as it will inform us what that structure *really* is. For example, `Hmisc::rcorr(as.matrix(list(1,2,3,4,5)))` works but `Hmisc::rcorr(as.matrix(list(1,2,3,list(4,5))))` and `Hmisc::rcorr(as.matrix(list(list(1,2,3,4,5))))` give your error.

Comment: @r2evans; likely it is not as complicated as that; `mtcars = lapply(mtcars, as.numeric) ; rcorr(as.matrix(mtcars))`

Comment: I think your previous recommendation to reassign with `nmdata_y1[] <- ...` will likely fix it, since `Hmisc::rcorr(as.matrix(lapply(mtcars, as.numeric)))` fails but `Hmisc::rcorr(as.matrix(as.data.frame(lapply(mtcars, as.numeric))))` succeeds. (Horribly-long code, but comments are bad for code anyway :-)